# Reading multiple files in directory and printing specific content

Tags: java, file, printing, bufferedreader, filereader

What I am trying to achieve is basically a Java file which looks through a specific directory on the users computer, search all the files in the directory for specific word (in this case an email) and then at the end print them out.

The current script of which I have now, looks for all the files in a certain directory, prints out those file names. As well as that I have also figured out how to have that script search through one file for a specific word and then print it out. The only problem is that although it searches through that one file and gets that word/phrase it has to be given the full directory and file to work. I just want it to have a specific directory and then search all the files in it. I have tried doing this using the directory variable of which I have created to find all files, but it does not work when using that as the directory for the files to search through to find the word(s).

Here underneath is the part of my code which is used for the function I want. The actual function is called in my real script so don't worry about that as it is working. I have also just commented in the script what variable I want to work where.

```
    package aProject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class aScanner {

    static String usernameMac = System.getProperty("user.name");
    final static File foldersMac = new File("/Users/" + usernameMac + "/Library/Mail/V2"); // this is the right directory I want to look through

    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File foldersMac) {
        for (final File fileEntry : foldersMac.listFiles()) {

            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);

                try {
                    BufferedReader bReaderM = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/username/Library/Mail/V2/AosIMAP-/INBOX.mbox/longnumber-folder/Data/Messages/1.emlx")); //this is where I would like the foldersMac variable to work in, instead of this full directory
                    String lineMe;
                    while((lineMe = bReaderM.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if(lineMe.contains(".com"))
                            System.out.println(lineMe);
                    }
                    bReaderM.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {

                }

            } else {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());

            }

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to close that reader, in case there is az IOException or any other behaviour. I would rather put that .close() method inside a finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class aScanner {

    static String usernameMac = System.getProperty("user.name");
    final static File foldersMac = new File("/Users/" + usernameMac + "/Library/Mail/V2");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        listFilesForFolder(foldersMac);
    }

    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File foldersMac) throws IOException {
        for (final File fileEntry : foldersMac.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                try (BufferedReader bReaderM = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileEntry))) {
                    String lineMe;
                    while ((lineMe = bReaderM.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (lineMe.contains(".com")) {
                            lines.add(lineMe);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath() + ":");
                    for (String line : lines) {
                        System.out.println("  " + line.trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write the code, I have tried to implement it into my code. But it is giving me a bunch of errors, I know I of course have to import all the plug ins, which I have done. But it is still giving me different errors which I am unable to fix. If you put the code into https://www.compilejava.net/ it will also give a bunch of errors. This is one of the errors i got in Eclipse `cannot instantiate the type ArrayList<?>`

Comment: I edited and added the required imports. It won't run in compilejava.net because the sandbox won't allow access to system properties or the file system, but it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies around your recursion logic,
You go down recursively in the directory structure, you walk through you tree, but write out nothing cause of this if statement:

```
if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);

...
}
```

Close that If statement earlier, then it should work.

Comment: I have changed it up as you said I think now, but the only thing which has changed. Is that now it only prints out the name of the files of which it already did, but not the actual content of it.